# Can we formulate our own Tafseer from our understanding of Qur'an?

Tags: quran, tafseer, hadith-interpretation, sin, uloom-al-hadith

> Narrated Jundab bin 'Abdullah:
>   that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Whoever says (something) about the Qur'an according to his own opinion and he is correct, yet he has committed a mistake."

And there are other versions of the same Hadith in "[Chapters on Tafsir - Jami` at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/47)" (the first three ones in that chapter).

1. What is the Hadith talking about when it says *"Whoever says (something) about the Qur'an..."*? Is it talking about formulating our own Tafseer of the Qur'an?
2. If yes, then does it mean we must follow the Tafseer given out by Prophet Muhammad (SAW) only or can we follow the Tafseer of other scholars too?
3. If only of Prophet Muhammad (SAW) and if I'm not wrong that Prophet Muhammad (SAW) hasn't explained about every verse of Qur'an, then doesn't it become difficult to understand the Qur'an?
4. If yes, to Q1 (above), then how is it possible that Qur'an while being clear and apparent most of the time still has to be relied on Tafseer? And only of Prophet Muhammad (SAW) (if Yes to Q2 above)?

Comment: Seen this too: "[Quran's human interpretation](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7411/9123)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link that you have provided. This Hadith is Da'if, which means weak. In the arabic section, it mentioned the narration chain. One of the narrators was Suhil bin Abdullah or named as well Suhil bin Abi Hazem according to what was mentioned in the arabic section is a weak narrator. That's why this Hadith is weak.

As for the point of your question, the whole idea of this section in the Hadith is to forbid people to try to interpret the Quran without studying and learning, in other words with out knowledge. According the site that you have quoted as well, this the opinion that the majority of the Scholars agreed upon.

Answer (score 2):

None of the authentic and accepted/renowned tafsirs till now are compilations of the individual author's thoughts on how he understood Quran.

The authors have given references and proofs from the life of the Prophet and the understanding of the sahaba to interpret Quran and that's what tafsir is.

Quran is very easy to understand. Allaah has made the Dos and Don'ts crystal clear. Our purpose in this life is not to chase any idea that might come to mind but to do useful deeds and be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is strange, I am not sure about your background but remember that mountains of work has been done on the Qur'an already. Why would one want to create his/her own tafsir when one has little knowledge of the deen? Little knowledge can be dangerous.

Do not forget that ALL of the deviant sects that have emerged in the past in Islam and perhaps for that matter in Judaism as well, have been because they wanted to interpret the Qur'an or the word of God, in a way different than what was prescribed by the Prophet and the companions. There are certainly things in the Qur'an that are ambiguous, some of them on purpose i.e their true meaning is known only to the one that revealed it. When people think that we know better, it leads to deviant sects.

Comment: Your answer goes against the word of Quran. `Verse 54:17 And We have indeed made the Qur'an easy to understand and remember: then is there any that will receive admonition?`

Comment: @user921 "understand" is an interpretation in the translation which, isn't necessarily correct! dhikr ذكر seems far away of being a synonym of understanding!

Answer (score -1):

Saying someone is of little knowledge seems prejudicial, which I reckon the answer-provider would rethink and reconsider in view of the fact that the prejudice is likely to cause someone being undermined. When a wise or learned person answers for the sake of clarity of the understanding of the religion or its scripture, that answer or opinion should be given in taqwa, given that this a prerequisite to being righteous.

A righteous heart should appreciate other fellow believers' concern with a view that this inquisitiveness in understanding and learning Qur'an may be a sign of the grace of God. Therefore, please encourage others to learn to study instead of suffocating them in the name of being scholastic, because the great religion Islam is based on the divine guidance, the Qur'an, and the Prophet Muhammad's (PBUH) true practice and teaching.

I, however, agree with your view that the Allah (SWT) proclaims that He sent the Qur'an easy to remember. However, at first, few readings might cause difficulty to understand, which one can overcome by dedicating him/herself to learn and understand the Qur'an only to please Allah (SWT)

And yes, you're right saying that there is a possibility being deviated, however, that deviation depends on an individual's own intention as to whether s/he is really wishing to learn or is derived from any other ulterior motive, which once again should be left for Allah to judge.

Please forgive me for the sake of God in the event any words might cause any discomfort.

Comment: This is not answering the question, but a commentary on another post! (See [answer]).